# Realm 0.99 Swift let realm = try! Realm()

Tags: swift, realm

Pulling my hair out here. Just did a pod update and sucked down Realm Swift 0.99.1 and everywhere I have the `let realm = try! Realm()` line I blow up with an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION. Stuff I have tried:

- Totally cleaning up the pods, caches, etc.
- Clean builds
- Searching everywhere (I think) for breaking changes on the new version.

I think I may have been on 0.96 before.

Help! :(

Comment: OK, but the one thing I forgot to do was clean the simulator since I had changed the DB between builds. So the problem was not Realm version, it was in not migrating the data (or cleaning it). Leaving this here in case anyone else pulls a big DERRF like me :D.

Answer (score 0):

It honestly could be as simple as having to delete the app from your simulator or device for testing. This has to do with the Realm file itself. Sometimes updates can cause movements of data that act as though they need a migration, in this case (unless you need the data in the realm file) I would simply uninstall the app and rebuild it.